# why my useAsyncQuery does not call up my api?

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo, nuxtjs3

I'm newbie and somehow I have no luck to call my localhost API.

Nuxt.config.ts

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    modules: ['@nuxtjs/apollo'],
    apollo: {
        clients: {
          default: {
            httpEndpoint: 'https://main--spacex-l4uc6p.apollographos.net/graphql'
          },
          other: {
            httpEndpoint: 'https://localhost:5001/api/data'
          },
        },
      },
})
```

App.vue: the ship api works well, my localhost api does not, though it works ok with postman test. Please help to point out what I have done it wrong ?

[image]

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>There are {{ data?.ships?.length || 0 }} ships.</p>
    <p>team {{ data2 }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts" setup>
const query = gql`
  query getShips($limit: Int!) {
    ships(limit: $limit) {
      id
      name
    }
  }
`;

const { data } = await useAsyncQuery(query, { limit: 5 }); // works

const query2 = gql`
  query getTeam($id: Int!) {
    team(id: $id) {
      id
      name
      
    }
  }
`;
const { data2 } = await useAsyncQuery(query2, { id: 41 }, "other");  // fails
</script>
```

Comment: What doesn't work with your query? Do you have an error? Don't you see the query in the network tab? Also, you should destruct your second query with `const { data: data2 }`. Because `data2` isn't a returned property.

Comment: thanks for your input, i changed to const { data } = await useAsyncQuery(query2, { id: 41 }, "other");  => just nothing happen, network fetch/xhr or console show nothing.

my old nuxt@apollo 4.0.1-rc.5 works just fine.

Comment: So if you downgrade the library version it works fine? Must be a bug in the latest version if so!